# What replaces SynchronizationContext in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core doesn't have `SynchronizationContext`.

So how can the continuation of `async` code resume to where it begin (the original thread)?

Comment: I believe nothing has replaced `SynchronizationContext` the class itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR The continuation don't have to return to original thread.

Stephen Cleary has nice explanation to why ASP.NET Core doesn't have SynchronizationContext.

> When an asynchronous handler resumes execution on legacy ASP.NET, the
>   continuation is queued to the request context. The continuation must
>   wait for any other continuations that have already been queued (only
>   one may run at a time). When it is ready to run, a thread is taken
>   from the thread pool, enters the request context, and then resumes
>   executing the handler. That “re-entering” the request context involves
>   a number of housekeeping tasks, such as setting HttpContext.Current
>   and the current thread’s identity and culture.
>
> With the contextless ASP.NET Core approach, when an asynchronous
>   handler resumes execution, a thread is taken from the thread pool and
>   executes the continuation. The context queue is avoided, and there is
>   no “entering” of the request context necessary. In addition, the
>   async/await mechanism is highly optimized for the contextless
>   scenario. There’s simply less work to do for asynchronous requests.
>
> [Read more](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html)

I also recommend to dig into comments there are a lot of helpfull stuff out there.